# Correct syntax for an OR conditional within a Matrix block

Tags: matrix, conditional

I have a dropdown Matrix block and need to check whether a selected value is either one or another.  If either value is selected I want to display some text on the front end.  At the moment I have `{% if block.wellFormattedContent =='toBeActioned' OR block.wellFormattedContent =='partiallyActioned' %}` but it errors.  Hopefully you can see what i'm trying to do.

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Try `or` in lowercase. You can learn more about the templating language here http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Comment: Also, if you haven't done so already, turn on dev mode in your config file (add the line `'devMode' => true,`), it'll give you much more descriptive errors making debugging so much easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted by @Benjammin' in the comments, the `or` operator has to be lowercase. See [Logic Expressions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#logic) in the Twig docs:

> Operators are case sensitive.

You also have to get the dropdown value explicitly by accessing its `value` property.

```
{% if block.wellFormattedContent.value == 'toBeActioned' or block.wellFormattedContent.value == 'partiallyActioned' %}
```

The short syntax `{{ block.wellFormattedContent }}` (which internally uses the field's `toString()` magic method) causes problems within Twig conditionals. You can probably also get around this issue by wrapping it in curly braces.

```
{% if (block.wellFormattedContent) == 'toBeActioned' or (block.wellFormattedContent) == 'partiallyActioned' %}
```

Comment: Thanks Carl (again)  :D  - Should also note Benjammin point that the OR should be lowercase.

Comment: Good to know, I thought it doesn't matter. Thanks @Martin and @Benjammin!